# Is there an editor for 4DOS btm files that support syntax highlighting and indentation?

Tags: windows, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, indentation

I'm reverse engineering a customer's `.btm` file (currently using **Win7**). Can I hope to find a text editor (or a Netbeans plugin) that supports indentation and syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) editor + try customizing BAT lexer for your needs. (or you may create a new lexer).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'm giving it a try this week (needs corporate approval, so it may take a few days until I can upvote you).